# How to calculate the critical DmodX value from a PCA?

Tags: statistical-significance, pca, residuals

R has a [DModX Calculation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pcaMethods/versions/1.64.0/topics/DModX%2CpcaRes-method) for PCA. I've seen references in some online texts that a critical DModX can be used to flag samples which are significantly poor fit to the model. The R documentation states that DModX is approximately F-distributed. How would I use the F Distribution to calculate the critical DModX value at a particular confidence interval given my PCA model? It seems there are several definitions of DModX in different software packages, each using different scaling parameters. Sticking to the definition used in R would be appreciated.

Comment: If by "definition used in R" you mean the link you provided, then be especially careful, because--at least at first glance--the statistic it defines looks like it is the *square root* of an F-distributed variable.

Comment: One source did say that DModX² is proportional to F. This is exactly why I'm asking, Thanks for your insight.